# How can I access a strongly typed partial view model from the parent view model?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4

I have a strongly typed partial view that consists of one form field.  I would like to add this partial view into all of the existing forms on a website(around 25 forms). I am having trouble figuring out how to reference the model information from the existing form controllers.  I am adding the partial view like so. `@{Html.RenderPartial("_HoneyPotFormField");}`  what I am looking to do is something to the effect of if HoneyPotFormFieldModel.Comments is null do something.

Here is my View code.

```
@model Web.Models.HoneyPotFormFieldModel
<div class="form-comments">
    <div class="title">
        <span>Comments</span>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-10">
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Comments)
    </div>
</div>
```

here is my Model code

```
public class HoneyPotFormFieldModel
{
    public string Comments { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: So you have a parent view with `Prop1`, you want to reference `Prop1` in a partial view??

Comment: Without having much more information, I think you should just create a new instance of the Model in the parent page(s) and pass it to the partial view. You can then use the instance in the parent page to do your null checking.

Comment: I have existing views that i would like to add the HoneyPotFormField view to, and then use the value from the HoneyPotFormField in the existing controllers.  So somehow I have to get combine the Honeypot model information with the existing model information.  I hope that make sense.

Comment: I know a partial view can access the parent's views properties. I don't know if a parent view can access a partial properties, since the partial view is rendered after the parent.

Comment: Sorry I should have mentioned that I do not need the information until the form is submitted.

Comment: thanks Wesley Vrancken that will work.  I think I was over thinking it.